# backbone.js illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, local-storage

http://jsfiddle.net/herrturtur/ExWFH/

To try this:

1. click the plus button,
2. double click the newly created name field,
3. fill something in for the fields
4. press Enter.

The era fields (from and until) get displayed properly, but aren't saved (reload to see the effect) and the Name field isn't updated at all.

I call `this.model.save()` after set()ting the attributes in NameView's close function (triggered by Enter-keypress) in line 153.

```
close: function(e){ 
    this.$el.removeClass('editing');
    this.model.set({
        value: this.$('.name-value').val(), 
        from: this.model.from, // this is saved in the 
        until: this.model.until
    });

    this.model.save();

    if(this.eraView.$el.attr('editing')){
        this.eraView.close();
    }
    this.render();
},
```

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

On top of everything, I get a TypeError: Illegal Invocation in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you're having is when calling the `close` function.

Within your `close` function, you're calling itself so it seems like a loop of redundancy.

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/efedun/1/edit)

On your `karass.EraView`, you're also triggering the same function within the function which is unnecessary. I would suggest renaming it to a different function that corresponds to the intent of the action.

```
this.trigger('close');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because of this:
`this.eraView.on('close', close);`

It should be: 
`this.eraView.on('close', this.close, this);`

Next, when you do this:

```
this.model.set({
            value: this.$('.name-value').val(), 
            from: this.model.from, 
            until: this.model.until
        });
```

`this.model.from` and `this.model.until` are undefined, plus you already set those attributes earlier.  The model already has them.  If you wanted to access them, you need to do `this.model.get('from')` instead of `this.model.from`.  But getting the value from the model and setting it again is unnecessary. You can just `set` value, since the other 2 are already there.

The other problem is similar.  When you render the NameView, you are doing:

`this.$el.html(this.template({value: this.model.value}));`

Same as before, you need to do `this.model.get('value')` instead.

You should try setting some breakpoints in Chrome and step through the code.  It is pretty easy to step through it and see what is going wrong :)

Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phoenecke/ExWFH/6/).